# Is ${C_0}(R)$ dense in ${L^1}(R)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let ${C_0}(R)$  be the space of all continuous function who have zero limit at infinity....It well kown that the space of continuous function who has compact support in $R$ is dense in $L^p(R)$ for p different from infinity.
he question is : is this space dense in ${L^1}(R)$ ? thanks.

Comment: Every compactly supported function has zero limit at infinity...

Comment: Are you sure that $C_0(\mathbb R)$ is even contained inside $L^1(\mathbb R)$? Isn't $f(x) = 1/(1+|x|)$ in $C_0(\mathbb R)$ but not in $L^1(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ is not fully contained in $L^1$.

Comment: So is not dense . thanks

Comment: $C_0 \cap L^1$ is dense in $L^1$. This follows from $\|f-f \ast h_n\|_{L^1} \to 0$ where $h_n(x)= n e^{-\pi n^2 x^2}$ and $\ast $ is the convolution

Comment: And If i take $C_0$ with out intesrection with $L^1$ ?

Comment: $\frac{1}{1+|x|}$ is not in $L^1$..